# Find missing element in arithmetic progression

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, indexof

I've been having trouble trying to get the proper index of list(I). Basically the algorithm sorts through a list of consecutive numbers such as 1,3,5,7,9,13 and returns which number is missing (11 in this case). My problem is that temp stays at -1, any idea on why? From my understanding, temp should increase as i gets incremented

```
    public static int FindMissing(List<int> list)
    {
        int difference;
        int missing = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            difference = list[1] - list[0];
            int temp = list.IndexOf(i);
            if (temp > 0)
            {
                if (list[i] - list[i - 1] != difference)
                {
                    missing = list[i - 1] + difference;
                }
            }
        }

        return missing;
    }
```

Alexandru Popa gave me a good answer, but for future people looking at this thread, someone showed me the continue keyword which ended up working like this

```
    public static int FindMissing(List<int> list)
    {
        int difference;
        int missing = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) continue;

            difference = list[1] - list[0];
            if (list[i] - list[i - 1] != difference)
            {
                missing = list[i - 1] + difference;
            }
        }
        return missing;
    }
```

Comment: If the list you provided is correct, temp will be -1,0,-1,1,-1,2. Are you completely sure that you are giving correct information?

Comment: You are looking for  IndexOf the index?  What if the list was 10 and started at 100.  You don't use difference = list[1] - list[0];

Comment: @paparazzo I'm looking for the IndexOf the current element in the list I'm looking at, so if the list elements are say, 1040,1220,1580, I would want only want the if statement to execute if I was on at least the 2nd element.

Comment: @TozuPug You need to edit that into your question instead of adding that as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make some changes in your code.

First, let's check if the list contains at least two elements, otherwise we shouldn't run the algorithm.

```
if(list.Count <= 2)
     return 0;
```

Second, move the declaration and initialization of *difference* out of the loop. As *difference* is constant, you shouldn't calculate it on each iteration.

```
    if(list.Count <= 2)
       return 0;

    int difference = list[1] - list[0];
```

Third, let's start the loop from index 2 as there's no need to check if *difference* equals *difference*.

```
    if(list.Count <= 2)
       return 0;

    int difference = list[1] - list[0];

    for (int i = 2; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
    }
```

Fourth, there is no need to check if your list contains its index, that's the sketchy part of your code, you only need to look at the differences between each neighbors. When one of them doesn't match up your initial difference you got your missing number. And we should return immediately, otherwise it can be overwritten if there are other missing elements in your list.

```
public static int FindMissing(List<int> list)
    {
        if(list.Count <= 2)
           return 0;

        int difference = list[1] - list[0];

        for (int i = 2; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i] - list[i - 1] != difference)
            {
                return list[i - 1] + difference;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

However this algorithm does not check for the integrity of the list. It only finds the first missing element in your list. It does not tell us whether the list contains other missing elements or not.

Comment: Yah this is what I was looking for, a friend of mine actually showed me a solution also involving if (i == 0) continue which also worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment in your question - you said that your list consist of elements: 1040,1220,1580.

Now in the for loop your index (i) will have the values 0,1,2.

Then your `temp` value will try to find the `IndexOf` the values of **i** - 0,1,2.

But in your list, there are no such values. Your values are 1040,1220,1580. So the `IndexOf` will always return -1.

*This is why you always see -1.*

Clear up a bit your question and code.

Comment: That would be really weird as list.IndexOf(list[i]) always evaluates to i as long as i is within the bounds of list. I thinks he starts with the wrong idea, trying to loop through each integer until he finds the elements in his list, instead of looping only though his list.

Comment: Yeah you are right - as I said, I can't get his idea, I was just helping him to figure out why he gets only -1. I'm removing this part of the answer. Thanks